# Can we use external npm packages in express js and react js as i am beginner in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I had started learning node js for backend development two or one month ago and I had learned many things like npm express js,mongoose and MongoDB as database while learning npm i learned we can download npm external packages and i am a python developer and i had been creating websites using django so in python django i was able to use python external libraries to make my work easy so can we do same in express js node js this is my question please help me if you know the answer

Comment: Sure, go for it.. it'd be pretty difficult to write absolutely everything from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can download any packages!
you need only download node js and you will have npm.
After that you can download any packages only run this command:
npm i packagename
more information about packages please visit these site https://www.npmjs.com/

Comment: so we can use any external packages with express js and react js as u only talked about downloading the packages in your answer

Comment: can you use express and react?

Comment: yes we can use react js as frontend and express js as backend but my question was only can we use external libraries of npm with express js

Comment: yes you can use