# can we use external node modules with express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hey i had asked this question before but was not able to find the correct answer. So please help me.

My Question is :-
Can we use external libraries of node js with express js

As I am beginner and learning express js and node js.

let's imagine I am creating a website using express js and I want to add some functionality in it. So I searched about that functionality and I found a npm package Ok. So now I have question that I am creating the website using node js and express js so can I install the package and use it in my express js website. So in the end my question is can I use external node modules in my express js website?

Comment: Please elaborate. What package do you want to use? Why is it not working right now? Maybe add the code your working with so we get a better understanding of the problem

Comment: *"i had asked this question before"* Why does the answer on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72419956/can-we-use-external-npm-packages-in-express-js-and-react-js-as-i-am-beginner-in) not suffice?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah sure you can use external packages in your express js application, just do "npm i <package_name>" and then require it, and use it.